# setting state of windows phone toolkit toggle switch

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-toolkit, ischecked, toggleswitch

I'm working on a windows phone 8 application. I want to use toggle switch for some purposes. Sadly windows phone 8 does not have that controller. So i had to install windows phone toolkit nuget package.

Now I want to set the state(some thing like isChecked=true). but I couldn't find any method to use.
can someone please help me.

Comment: There are plenty of examples how to Save/Load values. [Some information from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg680266(v=pandp.11).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on Button Click

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (toggleSwitch.IsChecked == true)
        toggleSwitch.IsChecked = false;
    else
        toggleSwitch.IsChecked = true;
}
```

It is Working....